# find variations of a word in a string on python

Tags: python, list

So, I'm running Python 3.3.2, I have a string (sentence, paragraph(s)):

```
mystring=["walk walked walking talk talking talks talked fly flying"]
```

And i have another list with words i need to search in that string:

```
list_of_words=["walk","talk","fly"]
```

And my question is, is there a way to get as result:

1. The word walk or a variation is present 3 times
2. The word talk or a variation is present 4 times
3. The word fly or a variation is present 2 times

Bottom line, is it possible to get a count on all possible variations of a word?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_stemming#Algorithms and http://nltk.org/ might be interesting to you.

Comment: do you always have the base form of a word in `list_of_words`? or could you have `list_of_words=['walks','flew','talking']`?

Comment: See my answer please. - You should precise what you mean by "variation". Because the kind of variation your question exposes leads to my code in which I wrote ``if x in y`` to eliminate the fact that ``talk`` is detected as a variation of ``walk`` by ``difflib``. But this makes my code stupid, since there is therefore no need to use ``difflib``: the only test ``if x in y`` would suffice. But I suppose that your real case is more sphisticated than the sample you wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from difflib import get_close_matches
mystring="walk walked walking talk talking talks talked fly flying"
list_of_words=["walk","talk","fly"]

sp = mystring.split()
for x in list_of_words:
    li = [y for y in get_close_matches(x,sp,cutoff=0.5) if x in y]
    print '%-7s %d in %-10s' % (x,len(li),li)
```

result

```
walk    2  in ['walk', 'walked']
talk    3  in ['talk', 'talks', 'talked']
fly     2  in ['fly', 'flying']
```

The cutoff refers to the same ratio as computed by `SequenceMatcher` :

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

sq = SequenceMatcher(None)
for x in list_of_words:
    for w in sp:
        sq.set_seqs(x,w)
        print '%-7s %-10s %f' % (x,w,sq.ratio())
```

result

```
walk    walk       1.000000
walk    walked     0.800000
walk    walking    0.727273
walk    talk       0.750000
walk    talking    0.545455
walk    talks      0.666667
walk    talked     0.600000
walk    fly        0.285714
walk    flying     0.200000
talk    walk       0.750000
talk    walked     0.600000
talk    walking    0.545455
talk    talk       1.000000
talk    talking    0.727273
talk    talks      0.888889
talk    talked     0.800000
talk    fly        0.285714
talk    flying     0.200000
fly     walk       0.285714
fly     walked     0.222222
fly     walking    0.200000
fly     talk       0.285714
fly     talking    0.200000
fly     talks      0.250000
fly     talked     0.222222
fly     fly        1.000000
fly     flying     0.666667
```

Comment: A problem with this approach is that `walking` is considered more similar to `talking` than to `walk`...

Comment: The problem with the question is that one can wonder on which criterium ``walking`` should be considered more similar to ``walk`` than to ``talking``. Because they start the same ? Then ``unwilling`` and ``unwind`` will be more similar than ``unwilling`` and ``willing`` ?

Comment: From his example I got a strong impression that what the OP really means is conjugations (and tenses). So what counts is that words stem from the same verb. Of course, there's much to be specified still.

Comment: the first method was what i needed thanks, i just modified some extra logic i needed! just one question, when you do the .split(), obviously, we "a list of lists of strings" per say so, how can i get as result certain amount of words before and after a word if i can't use .find()? for example: i know a variation of "talk" is 3 times on the text, and i want to get the 2 words before talk + talk + the 2 words after talk. Is there a command to do this?

Comment: by the way, when i mean variation  i mean tenses

Comment: Splitting produces a list of words, not a list of list of words. - I don't understand your question. What do you mean with ``talk + talk +`` ? If you want to get 2 words before and 2 words after a given word, you should use a regex ``re.compile('(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+talk\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)')`` - The answers I wrote are just basic information linked to your problem, they aren't elaborate answers to give precise resolution. My intent is to give you the possibility to develop your own solution excatly adapted to what you want and that we don't know exactly.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I feel that this discussion wouldn't be complete without mentioning the NLTK library, which provides a ton of Natural Language Processing tools, including one that can perform this task pretty easily.

Essentially, you want to compare the uninflected words in the target list to the uninflected forms of the words in the mystring.  There are two common ways of removing inflections (eg. -ing -ed -s): stemming or lemmatizing.  In English, lemmatizing, which reduces a word to its dictionary form, is usually better, but for this task, I think stemming is right.  Stemming is usually faster anyway.

```
mystring="walk walked walking talk talking talks talked fly flying"
list_of_words=["walk","talk","fly"]

word_counts = {}

from nltk.stem.snowball import EnglishStemmer
stemmer = EnglishStemmer()

for target in list_of_words:
    word_counts[target] = 0

    for word in mystring.split(' '):

        # Stem the word and compare it to the stem of the target
        stem = stemmer.stem(word)        
        if stem == stemmer.stem(target):
            word_counts[target] += 1

print word_counts
```

Output:

```
{'fly': 2, 'talk': 4, 'walk': 3}
```

Answer (score 2):

One method might be to split the string by spaces, then look for all the words that contain the particular word you want to find a variation for.

For example:

```
def num_variations(word, sentence):
    return sum(1 for snippit in sentence.split(' ') if word in snippit)

for word in ["walk", "talk", "fly"]:
    print word, num_variations(word, "walk walked walking talk talking talks talked fly flying")
```

However, this method is somewhat naive and wouldn't understand English morphology. For example, using this method, "fly" would not match "flies".

In that case, you might need to use some sort of natural language library that comes equipped with a decent dictionary to catch these edge cases.

You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13237605/646543) useful. It accomplishes something similar by using the [NLTK](http://nltk.org/) library to find the stem of the word (removing plurals, irregular spellings, etc) then summing them up using a method similar to the one above. It may be overkill for your case though, depending on precisely what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Need an `in` here: `return sum(1 for snippit in sentence.split(' ') if word in snippit)`

Comment: Ah, my mistake. It should be fixed now.

Comment: any ideas of why i get invalid syntax on "word" in line "print word, num_variations...."?

Comment: @rodrigocf -- Are you using Python 3? If so, you need to add parenthesis after `print` to make it a function call. (Also note that I made a minor change to the first line that fixed an unrelated bug)